# Find a word inside specific tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, dom

```
  let find_word="xyz"
       let el=document.getElementById("text");
        let arr = el.innerHTML.split(" ");
let newarr=[];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i] === find_word) {
            newarr[i] = `<span class="highlight">${arr[i]}</span>`;
          } else {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
          }
        }
el.innerHTML=newarr.join(" ")
```

I highlighted the two xyz's in the sentence but I can't highlight the others I need to highlight the xyz's in the li tags but not in the subtag

```
<div id="text"> Nature, in xyz broadest xyz 
<ul>
<li>xyz</li>
<li>xyz</li>
</ul> 
<sub>xyz</sub> <sub>xyz</sub> sense of world.</div>
```

Please give me a better example of doing this. I am not good at regex. I just know the basic regex. If regex can be a solution for this. suggest me some , please.

Comment: Typically trying to parse XML, html or anything like that with regex is a bad idea. Instead, you should use a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edits in the question, try this:

```js
el.innerHTML.split(/\b/);
```

The thing is that "xyz" is not surrounded by spaces in the places you are missing.

\b indicates a word boundary, so it will capture your missing occurences.

Note that, depending on what you are doing, it might be not completely safe, e.g. if the li element could have `class="xyz"` things will likely get messed up.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I am sorry vincent for not giving proper details. I just edited it. Could you please go through it and suggest me some examples please!? I am a beginner in coding and am trying for 2 days to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Yadharth, no worries: I have updated the answer; hopefully it will hint you towards the right direction